# getting error ContentBlockerErrorDomain Code=3 in adblocker

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting error in loading content blocker by creating group: When i provide list of small number of rules in content blocker the error didn't came, but when i add more rules in my blocker list it gives error, It means there is limit of data to provide on App Group? Any one followed some other approach please share

```
ContentBlockerErrorDomain Code=3
```

Comment: There is a limit of 50k entry, how many rules are you adding?

Comment: Where it is mention there is limit of 50K, can you give apple doc link for this.

Comment: For some reason I couldn't find anything about that limitation in Apple's doc.  But looking at WebKit code `ContentExtensionParser.cpp line:269` You can see it's there.

Comment: Here is a direct link to the same file

http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/contentextensions/ContentExtensionParser.cpp#L269

Comment: same problem here if any body fix this issue please submit a answer here

Answer (score 0):

i think that you are facing this issue while using NSUserdefault 
after setting object in UserDefault you need to synchronize it . that thing you missed:

once apply this :

```
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()["key"] = "value"
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

Comment: No, I didn't miss synchronize